# Output file in a certain way via Java

Tags: java

Having a little bit of an issue. I have successfully output a file based on the timestamp order, however, theres another condition i am trying to add also to alphabetically order if the time stamp is the same.

for example:

[TIMESTAMP = 12:30][EVENT=B]

[TIMESTAMP = 12:30][EVENT=U]

[TIMESTAMP = 12:30][EVENT=A]

and i want it to output

[TIMESTAMP = 12:30][EVENT=A]

[TIMESTAMP = 12:30][EVENT=B]

[TIMESTAMP = 12:30][EVENT=U]

my current code at the moment stands:

```
package Organiser;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Organiser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String directory = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1";
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(directory + ".txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(directory + "_ordered.txt");

        while (fileIn.hasNextLine() == true) {
            lines.add(fileIn.nextLine());
            Collections.sort(lines);
            System.out.println("Reading...");
        }

        for (String output : lines) {
            out.println(output + "\n");
        }

        out.close();
        System.out.println("Complete - See " + directory + "_ordered.txt");
    }
}
```

any ideas

EDIT: this is only for sample data, i only want this to occur when the time stamps the same, otherwise, it will order accordingly as per the time stamp.

Sample file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/611psg6qw4nl9pw/ex1.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

1. you should not sort your `Collection` everytime you add a line! Put the `Collections.sort(lines);` after the while-loop
2. The resulting code should already do the trick... I've tested it on my system and it worked!

Comment: On a much larger scale where I have multiple TIMESTAMPS, the output file will end up being organised based on the EVENT and not the TIME STAMP. I want to retain the order of the TIMESTAMP but when the TIMESTAMP times are the same, only the, order it by EVENT.

Comment: @MubeenHussain that's exactly what is happening... you might want to show us a little more information (e.g. the content of the file) so we can detect other issues that would cause the problems

Answer (score 0):

It should happen by default. (since 'U' > 'B' > 'A')

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        lines.add("[TIMESTAMP = 12:30][EVENT=B]");
        lines.add("[TIMESTAMP = 12:30][EVENT=A]");
        lines.add("[TIMESTAMP = 12:30][EVENT=U]");

        // unsorted
        System.out.println(lines);
        // default sorting of Strings will sort A before U
        Collections.sort(lines);
        System.out.println(lines);
    }
```